# Seperate strings in a list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index list of strings [List1] as shown below:

```
['2020-09-03\t06:15:55\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................,
 '2020-09-03\t07:32:19\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................,
 '2020-09-03\t07:33:49\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................]
```

How can I extract only the first and second strings only into a dataframe?

I have tried using:

```
[x for xs in List1 for x in xs.split('\t')]
```

But this made the list more complicated by including the remainder of the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split and use `.str[0:2].agg('\t'.join)`.:

1. `.str[0:2]` grabs the first two welements of a list you created with `split`
2. and `.agg('\t'.join)` joins those two items together in a string

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'List1' :  ['2020-09-03\t06:15:55\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................',
 '2020-09-03\t07:32:19\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................',
 '2020-09-03\t07:33:49\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................']})
df['List1'] = df['List1'].str.split('\t').str[0:2].agg('\t'.join)
df
Out[1]: 
                  List1
0  2020-09-03\t06:15:55
1  2020-09-03\t07:32:19
2  2020-09-03\t07:33:49
```

If you want is separate columns, then use `expand=True` in a secnd split:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'List1' :  ['2020-09-03\t06:15:55\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................',
 '2020-09-03\t07:32:19\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................',
 '2020-09-03\t07:33:49\tLocal0\tInfo\.....................']})
df[['List1', 'List2']] = df['List1'].str.split('\t').str[0:2].agg('\t'.join).str.split('\t', expand=True)
df
Out[2]: 
        List1     List2
0  2020-09-03  06:15:55
1  2020-09-03  07:32:19
2  2020-09-03  07:33:49
```

Answer (score 1):

You may:

1. Convert your *list of strings* (`list1` - note the lowercase “**L**” to be in concordance with [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions))  to the *(only) string with newline characters delimiting original strings.*
2. Then use this string as a *phantom file.*
3. Read this phantom file using the pandas `read_csv()` function to take full advantage of its *rich set of parameters:*

```
import io
import pandas as pd

list1 = ['2020-09-03\t06:15:55\tLocal0\tInfo\t.....................',
         '2020-09-03\t07:32:19\tLocal0\tInfo\t.....................',
         '2020-09-03\t07:33:49\tLocal0\tInfo\t.....................']

as_string = '\n'.join(list1)
as_file = io.StringIO(as_string)

df = pd.read_csv(as_file, sep='\t', header=None, usecols=[0, 1], names=['date', 'time'])
```

---

*The resulting `df`:*

> ```
>          date      time
> 0  2020-09-03  06:15:55
> 1  2020-09-03  07:32:19
> 2  2020-09-03  07:33:49
> ```